# excel vba 2007 Private sub to auto change a cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello one and all i have been trying to get a macro to auto run
when someone selects a cell. It would be nice if they didnt have to select the cell it just auto does it like an endless loop lol :D

anyway the code i have is this

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim RRnumber As Integer

    If Target.Column = E3 Then

        Sheets("RR LOG").Select
            lastRow = Sheets("RR LOG").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            RRnumber = Range("H" & lastRow).Value
            RRnumber = RRnumber + 1
        Sheets("RR").Select
            Range("E3").Value = RRnumber
    End If
    End Sub
```

i have the code saved in the "ThisWorkbook" what is the work book im working in :D ty for any help one can give in the errors of my ways :D

Comment: i have try to place the code in "Module 1" and still it does not work. 
Inside the "ThisWorkbook" i have an Workbook_Open code that works fine so im thinking it has something to do with the coding as when i click cell E3 nothing happens what should be starting up the marco PS) why did my post get a -1 ? be nice if they said why :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that code into the module that's associated to the worksheet for the procedure to fire. See the picture below for where to double click and add the code.

[image: Example]

As for the 'endless loop', excel requires an event to be completed by the user to fire a VBA procedure like the `SelectionChange` event that you've tried to use in your example.

One other thing worth mentioning is that as you're using excel 2007, you'll probably want to delcrae `lasatRow` as the data type `Long` as the limit for an integer is just over 32k (so if you have more than 32k rows, an error will be thrown using the `Integer` type). Also, can you guarantee that `Range("E3")` will be an integer less than 32k? if not, you probably want to use the `Long` datatype or even `String` in case of alphanumerical entries.

Comment: yeah i already knew that the endless loop was a lost :D Anyway From what i can tell placing the code in "ThisWorkbook" should work as i have an Workbook_open in there that works fine and when i place the code even in the module 1 it still does not work  thinking there something wrong with the code but i just dont know :D and ty for the tip on the long i didnt know that (used to php :D)

Comment: The `Workbook_Open` event will work as it fires when the workbook is open. The `SelectionChange` event applies to a specific worksheet and wont work in `Module1`. See the updated answer to find where to add the code. Double click on the corresponding worksheet (where the red arrow is) and add the code into there.

Comment: i got it to work but then it would stop working when editing other macros and now i cant get it to work at all its like its been disable some how :D even made a new workbook and it still well not go off but yet other marcos still work and yes its saved in the "Sheet1 (RR)"